# Basic Unity app only shows black/empty on Hololens, no splash screen

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, hololens

Apologies in advance for any formatting errors

A friend & I followed the steps [MR Basics 100: Getting started with Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-100) and everything is fine until building the solution in Unity and **deploying from Visual Studio.**

The build & deploy succeed, but the app launch is **imperceptible** on the Hololens headset. Through testing, I decided to open the Settings app so I'd see it disappear when Visual Studio launches the app.

**There is no splash screen** (we didn't define any custom splash screen, so I'd expect the default 'Made with Unity' screen), nor is there any visible change/activity when the app launches.

I'm using the free/Community versions of VS 2017 and 2019, and the project was created with the free version of Unity 2019.2.0f1

[My Github for this basic Unity project with a single cube in front of the camera and MR Basics 100 Settings](https://github.com/BitterDone/HoloHello/tree/00-WilliamHoloHello/HoloLensDemo)

Note that Holographic Remoting **works as expected** in Ch 5:

> [Chapter 5 - Verify on device from Unity editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-100#chapter-5---verify-on-device-from-unity-editor)

[Imgur album of the below pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNYYv.jpg)

Visual Studio **Output from: Debug always** looked like this:

> Creating a new clean layout...
>
> Copying files: Total 53 mb to layout...
>
> Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
>
> Registering the application to run from layout...
>
> Deployment complete (0:00:53.714). Full package name: "Template3D_1.0.0.0_x86__pzq3xp76mxafg"
>
> ========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Summary of Unity Build Settings variations attempted w/ Imgur refs:

- [Default build settings, added the open sample scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbvOT.png)
- [The 18362 isn't available on HL1, only HL2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYqOw.png)
- [Adding the Hololens as a Remote Device target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFik5.png)
- [Added Hololens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIQxc.png)

Hololens Windows 10.0.17763.914

1.

**initial / no change**: followed MS default steps:

Target Device: Any Device

Architecture: left as x64

Target SDK Version: Latest Installed (10.0.18362.0?)

Opened with VS 2019

2.

first change

Target Device: Any Device

Architecture: left as x64

**Target SDK Version**: manually set to 10.0.17763.0

Opened with VS 2019

3.

second change

Target Device: Any Device

**Architecture**: now, was changed to x86

**Target SDK Version**: still manually set to 10.0.17763.0

Opened with VS 2019

4.

third change

Target Device: Any Device

**Architecture**: still changed to x86

**Target SDK Version**: manually set to 10.0.17763.0

Opened with **VS 2017**

5.

https://medium.com/@mkryaz/step-by-step-hololens-1-with-unity-and-visual-studio-tutorial-4601d5dfcc8f
 - Step 4.9 about half way down

The app auto-launched from VS 2017 onto the HL when the Debug output was ~75% through the lines like: 'HoloLensDemo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.

Same result as all previous- no Unity splash screen, only black/empty

- [VS 2017 window during build/deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2AcL.png)
- [VS 2019 during build/deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3160.png)
- [VS 2017 steps from mkryaz on medium.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDMuh.png)

**Update from Sunius' comment**

- I didn't see any message about "symbols finished" / etc, but the long list of `HoloLensDemo.exe (Win32): Loaded C:\Windows\System32\ClipboardServer.dll. Symbols loaded.` lines stopped, there were a few lines like `HoloLensDemo.exe (Win32): Unloaded C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll`, and two lines of `The thread 0x12b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0)` so I figured it was done. VS auto-launches the app during deploy, out of my control.
- I'll find out how to check network activity.
- Same result manually opening the app. Full output: pastebin.com/fLXxvaFW

Comment: That's a ton of detail which will take some time to parse. In the mean time, are you using a personal or Pro license? The "Made with Unity" splash isn't included by default with Pro.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It's a lot, but I wanted to over-explain instead of under-explain. I'm using the free/Community versions of VS 2017 and 2019, and updated the question with this info.

Comment: 3Dave's question referred to the Unity Version though ;)

Comment: Any chance VS was still loading symbols? How long did you wait after the launch and was there any network activity on your PC? What happens when you launch the app directly through HoloLens start menu?

Comment: @3Dave my mistake, for Unity the project was created with 2019.2.0f1. I have 2018.4.14f1, 2019.2.0f1, 2019.2.6f1, 2019.2.7f1, and 2019.3.0f1 installed on my computer.

Comment: Thank you @derHugo, I updated & replied

Comment: @Sunius tyvm!  I didn't see any message about "symbols finished" / etc, but the long list of 
`HoloLensDemo.exe (Win32): Loaded C:\Windows\System32\ClipboardServer.dll. Symbols loaded.` lines stopped, there were a few lines like 
`HoloLensDemo.exe (Win32): Unloaded C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll`, and two lines of 
`The thread 0x12b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0)` so I figured it was done.

VS auto-launches the app during deploy. 

I'll find out how to check network activity.

Same result manually opening the app.

Full output: https://pastebin.com/fLXxvaFW

Comment: Did you modify generated project built from Unity? Do any other apps on the HoloLens work? Did you try rebooting the device? This line in the log: "Renderer: Microsoft Basic Render Driver (ID=0x8c)" suggests the graphics driver didn't initialize correctly and fell back to using WARP.

Comment: Just a shot: Try using Single-Pass instead of Multi-Pass in the PlayerSettings -> XR settings

Comment: @Sunius, turns out Unity 2017 worked right away. Thank you for the help! To answer your questions though: didn't modify, other stock apps work, didn't try rebooting.

Comment: @derHugo, turns out Unity 2017 worked right away but thank you for the help!

Comment: @3Dave thank you for the help! Turns out I need to use Unity 2017 LTS

Answer (score 2):

Had similar case, except the missing splash screen. My app didnt crash, output didnt show any errors and my cursor was gone. The reason for that was a **wrong configured clipping plane**. Had to change in the editor the value of near clipping. But this happend in HTK, a year ago...
Did you place something really big with the same coordinates (vector.zero) as your spawning coordinates, so that you "spawn" inside of an object?

Comment: Interesting idea, but no, the only object in the scene is the cube a few meters in front of the Camera that's at 0,0,0.

Turns out falling back to the Unity 2017 LTS version worked right away  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ From what I saw, every doc on Microsoft's sites says 2018 LTS+ and that they should be backward compatible with Hololens 1

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Unity 2017 LTS worked right away. I'd seen it as an option in Unity Hub, but didn't try it because all the docs say Unity 2018 LTS or 2019, and they're supposed to be backward compatible with Hololens 1  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

It's unclear to me how a reader is supposed to gather this from the docs:

> The current recommendation is to use Unity 2018.4.x, which is the LTS build required for MRTK v2 below.
>
> MRTK v2 is intended to accelerate development of applications targeting Microsoft HoloLens, [...]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools