# Hololens 2 Unity app rarely renders anything to the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

So this question I think is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349145/basic-unity-app-only-shows-black-empty-on-hololens-no-splash-screen) but the solution for this problem was downgrading to Unity 2017 LTS, which is incompatible with my current project.

Basically, whenever I build, there's maybe a 10% chance that the app runs in the Hololens. Most of the time however, no floating balls animation pops up, no Unity splash screen appears, and I don't see any of my app content. Strangely enough, the app does ask for microphone permissions, but that's all. It should ask for eye tracking too, but it doesn't. (Not sure if that's related but I'm out of ideas.) On a proper run, I get the floating balls, Unity splash, and all permissions asked before the content. The most frustrating part is that it *sometimes* works, and there has been no trend at all towards what helps or what doesn't.

I've tried rebuilding in Unity, redeploying in VS, reinstalling the appx, updating VS, updating Windows, and checked every forum post I could find but I can't figure this out. Does anyone have any ideas?

I thought it might be an OpenXR / Holographic remoting problem, but those have both been dead ends. Really not sure what to do at this point. Thanks in advance.

Unity version: 2020.3.36f1,
VS 2022, MRTKv2, HoloLens 2

Comment: Have you tried looking into the log files? Maybe there is some exception or you have a freeze (infinite loop) somewhere? You should [Debug your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/managed-debugging-with-unity-il2cpp) (see also [Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)) and check line-by-line until where exactly the app runs correctly

Comment: Downgrade certainly is not a satisfactory solution, since you are using OpenXR and MRTKv2. Does HoloLens 2 display only hand rays with a blank screen? Would you create a new Unity Project and import the latest MRTK with MR Feature tools again, then migrate Unity assets from the previous project? This issue can be caused by corrupted MRTK configuration files.

Comment: @derHugo i'll try this out today. thanks for the links

Comment: @SethDU-MSFT admittedly i have not tried this yet, i initially saw this as a last resort kind of thing but maybe i'll give it a shot if the debugging doesn't work.

Comment: oh and also make sure you really terminate the app ... Hololens unfortunately only hibernates apps until you actually hard kill them by closing the according widget in your home "screen"/space

Comment: Debugging has brought me to the conclusion that there are some unhandled errors on build... the most common one is a stack overflow caused by some infinite loop but idk how to handle it because its in the IL2CPP code, not in my unity project's code

Comment: @SethDU-MSFT just tried a new project - same error on the first build...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone! For some reason, my solution is just as confusing as the problem, but it seems to reliably work.

Problem has something to do with the Holographic Remoting for OpenXR, so simply enabling and then disabling that feature in the editor right before building seems to fix a buggy build. Tested this a few times now and it works pretty consistently. Hope this can help someone and eventually get patched.

**EDIT**: Previous answer didn't work. Now I'm thinking the problem was actually caused by a toggle in the Project Settings. For a successful build it seems as though XR Plug-in Management > Windows Mixed Reality > UWP > **Use Primary Window** should be checked **on**. Seems weird since I'm using OpenXR anyways, but this might help someone so thought I'd update. Works most of the time now - needs more testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. Use "Windows Mixed Reality" plug-in provider.
2. Use "OpenXR plugin". For this case the order of installation of packages plays important role:

- When you create new project, manually install OpenXR plugin using Package Manager of Unity.
- Using "Mixed Reality Feature Tool", install other features of MRTK2 including "Mixed Reality Open XR plugin" in "Platform Support".
  [XR Plug-in Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T51cU.png)
  [OpenXR features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMFkr.png)