# HoloLens 2 Unity App doesn't render anything on screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I do realize that my question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73116543/hololens-2-unity-app-rarely-renders-anything-to-the-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1) one. However, I've tried the proposed solutions and nothing seems to work.

I'm trying to develop a simple app for the HoloLens 2 using Unity and MRTK. I have no problems building the app on unity and then building + deploying it on VS. However, when I run the app on the hololens, it shows absolutely nothing, no "Made with Unity" splash screen, no cubes floating around, and no mrtk diagnostics bar (I left it in to see if it was rendered on the hololens). I have added an audio source to one of the cubes in the scene and I can hear it when I launch the app, and a popup window asking for permission to use the microphone appears on the first deploy, thus I think that something is being done correctly, but that's as far as it goes.

I've tried recreating the app from scratch in unity numerous times, I've also tried some different versions of unity, I've tried different settings in the player settings and in the MRTK settings, but I haven't figured out anything. Does anyone have any ideas or has encountered a similar problem before? Thanks in advance.

Unity Version (currently being used): 2020.3.19f1
Visual Studio 2022 Community edition
MRTKv2
HoloLens 2

Comment: For Unity, it is recommended to use the latest LTS version of 2020.3 for testing. Have you tried the example scenes in the **Mixed Reality Toolkit Examples** package? For example Hand interaction examples - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/example-scenes/hand-interaction-examples?view=mrtkunity-2022-05, does it work? Also, you can find the log file in **Device Portal->System->File explorer->LocalAppData->[ProjectName]->TempState**, please check if there is any error message.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem. I am running Unity 2020.3.37, MRTK 2, Hololens 2 VS 2022.

No idea why it is not working...

I tried rebooting the Hololens 2, reset all factory settings, reconnect to device portal... I wonder whether Microsoft updated something that has a conflict with MRTK 2. They are working on MRTK 3 so I wonder whether they changed something...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-overview/

Answer (score 0):

For this one, nothing new reported as of yet.  That said, MRTK 2 is in maintenance mode with recommendation to go to MRTK3 which is in active development and updating for HL2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/known-issues